# Is there any way in Nuxt3 to load a plugin once?

Tags: vue.js, sequelize.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to integrate [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/) to my [Nuxt 3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/) project. However, I couldn't figure out how to make it load only once instead of reloading it every time the page was refreshed / navigating to another routes.

I couldn't find any information on the docs. Is it even possible?

`~/plugins/sequelize.server.ts`

```js
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize"

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.dbName, config.dbUser, config.dbPass,{
        host: config.dbHost,
        port: parseInt(config.dbPort),
        dialect: 'mysql',
    })

    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate()

        // this log was executed every time I navigate to a new route
        // or refreshing the browser.
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    }
    
    return {
        provide: {
            db: sequelize
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (have the behavior changed from Nuxt2 to Nuxt3?) but a plugin is loaded for the whole time you have your Vue instance. Hence, if you make a client side navigation, nothing should change: the plugin should still be globally available and loaded only once. If you reload the page, you nuke the whole app so you will re-download it (I don't see how you could not).

Comment: I'm not sure about the behavior from Nuxt2 but I think it should be loaded the way you said. But the fact is, it was reinitialized on every page transition*, which is weird. *can confirm this by looking at the message: `Connection has been established successfully.` which is printed every time I navigate to different pages.

Comment: Do you have a [repro] for that one?

Comment: Ahhhhh... It was me! I made a composable that initializes it in one of my component's `mounted` hooks and forgot to delete it. I realized it moment after I try to make a reproduction repo. Silly me! ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP solved his issue by removing a composable that was initialized on a component's `mounted` lifecycle hook.

Just a remaining piece of code.